# twilio 5.7.0 send message sample give exception

Tags: python, twilio

I am using windows 10 and I want to use twilio API , so first by terminal I installed the twilio and the install success , then to check every thing ok I run this code :

```
import twilio
print twilio.__version__
```

the output is :
5.7.0

Now I want to send message to my phone , I signup and get my account_sid ,auth_token , twilio number and register in my phone number which I want to send message to it , I try to run  this code after I replaced my account_sid ,auth_token , twilio number and register in my phone number But it give exeception this is the code :

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
import twilio
print twilio.__version__
# Your Account SID from twilio.com/console
account_sid = "AC6791725bc93116fbd42b4cd477996f7d"
# Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
auth_token  = "30ed212f6a2bbc05d103b67426b8509a"

client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.sms.messages.create(
    body="Sent from your Twilio trial account - hello from python",
    to="my number phone goes here",
    from_="+14695356845" )

print message.sid
```

the runtime error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Black_Swan/PycharmProjects/omac1/send message.py", line 14, in <module>
    from_="+14695356845" )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twilio\rest\resources\sms_messages.py", line 167, in create
    return self.create_instance(kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twilio\rest\resources\base.py", line 365, in create_instance
    data=transform_params(body))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twilio\rest\resources\base.py", line 200, in request
    resp = make_twilio_request(method, uri, auth=self.auth, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twilio\rest\resources\base.py", line 164, in make_twilio_request
    uri=resp.url, msg=message, code=code)
twilio.rest.exceptions.TwilioRestException: HTTP 451 error: IP Address: 5.0.217.104
```

any help what I do mistake ?

Answer (score 2):

First, I encourage you to use Python 3 instead Python 2, you'll be a better person.

About the error, it returns a 451 http error, doing a quick search in Google, I got this: [**HTTP 451 Unavailable For Legal Reasons**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_451)

I'm going to give you possible solutions:

1. Check if your phone can send messages: Go to Dashboard -> Phone Numbers - Manage Numbers -> Click on your Twilio number. Here on the bottom you can see in "Messaging" if you can send SMS. I can't and I have a "Messaging is unavailable for this phone number." message.
2. Check if you have your country enable to send SMS: [SMS Geographic Permissions](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181108-How-International-SMS-Permissions-work) link.
3. The other option (and most likely) is that Twilio can't send you SMS to your country for legal reasons. [Here](https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing/us) you can check if there is any problem with sending messages from your Twilio phone to your phone country.

I hope it helps

Comment: This is a great answer! Thanks Daniel (I work at Twilio).  I'd add one other thing, calling `client.sms.messages.create` uses an old and deprecated API. I would update to just `client.messages.create` and you might get better results.

Comment: @philnash Still got 451 by trying the totally same CURL code on your doc after eliminating all the issues mentioned!

Comment: @Suge Did you try the things in the answer above? The 451 error is likely not a code issue, but something to do with your account, so running the code from the docs may not work until you fix that.